# How to remove Closing event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling, formclosing

I have found a nice example of how to remove all *Click* events from a form:

```
private void RemoveClickEvent(Form c)
{
    var f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var obj = f1.GetValue(c);
    var pi = c.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(c, null);
    list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
}
```

and it works well. However, what I need is to remove Closing event but I have no clue as of what to write instead of `EventClick` to make it work. I tried to write `EventClosing`, `Closing`, but that didn't work. Thus my question is: **what should be changed to make it work?** Even better - I would like to find **a list of all possible inputs** there since I might need to remove other events like `Closed`, `FormClosing`, `FormClosed`, etc.

P.S. a simple `-=` is not possible since there can be many events attached many of them not accessible to me at all thus I wouldn't be able to remove them anyway.

Comment: Do you want force form not closing?

Comment: No, actually quite the opposite - I want to close it without any events firing except the standard close. For example: I want to prevent form from showing a MessageBox asking "There are unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to close?".

Comment: So when you click or try to close form it shows messageBox with question? I couldn't fully understand your problem, but cant you remove codes that display messagebox?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - it displays a dialog. I have no control over the form apart from creating it `var form = new MyForm(); form.ShowDialog();`. Then I want to close it with `form.Close();` however the dialog prevents the code from continuing and thus I want to get rid of it. I am doing a test of a few hundred of such forms and all I want to see is whether they opened successfully or not. Maybe there is another way to close the dialog itself, but I tried finding a difference between a form with a dialog and without one - the only difference was the value of CanFocus property.

Comment: I seem to have found the solution displaying the list of events with `typeof(Form).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).AsEnumerable().ToList()`

Comment: The Control class does not have a Closing event.  The Form class does.  It is `EVENT_CLOSING`.  Although you are surely meant to remove the FormClosing event, its secret cookie is `EVENT_FORMCLOSING`.

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks, I literally just found these names a second ago (see my comment above) and it worked!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I wasted my free time.

Comment: @HansPassant I do apologize not having been faster with finding a way myself. I posted my whole solution as an answer. I do appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I have come up with a list of these event names with this:

```
typeof(Form).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Now I have a method which looks like this:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static void DisableEvents<T>(this T ctrl, string officialName, string simplifiedName) where T : Control
    {
        var propertyInfo = ctrl.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var eventHandlerList = propertyInfo.GetValue(ctrl, new object[] { }) as EventHandlerList;
        var fieldInfo = typeof(T).GetField(officialName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        var eventKey = fieldInfo.GetValue(ctrl);
        var eventHandler = eventHandlerList[eventKey];
        var invocationList = eventHandler.GetInvocationList();

        foreach (var item in invocationList)
        {
            ctrl.GetType().GetEvent(simplifiedName).RemoveEventHandler(ctrl, item);
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage looks like this:

```
myForm.DisableEvents<Form>("EVENT_CLOSING", "Closing");
```

Unfortunately I am yet to have come up with a way to pass a single parameter to my method.

Answer (score 0):

According to the previous post, the usage have to be like this:

```
        myForm.DisableEvents<Form>("EVENT_FORMCLOSING", "FormClosing");
        myForm.DisableEvents<Form>("EVENT_FORMCLOSED", "FormClosed");
```